# dynamic programming - print all subsets with the given sum

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am practicing some dynamic programming problem and was trying to solve the problem to print all subsets with the given sum. For e.g. : For the `set :{1,2,3,4,5}` and `sum value = 10` , I should get the below results:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
```

I am getting the required result without using `table`, which I used to prevent repetitive calls for same `i` and `sum`. But I am not getting `[2, 3, 5]` in the output when using `table`.

```
    private static void printSubsetsWithSum(int i, int arr[], int sum, List<Integer> list, int j, boolean[][] table, Map<String,Integer> map) {
        if(sum == 0) {
            System.out.println(list);
        } else if(sum < 0 || i >= arr.length) {
            return;
        } else if(table[i][sum]) {
            return ;
        } else if(arr[i] > sum) {
            printSubsetsWithSum(i+1, arr, sum, list, j, table, map);
            table[i][sum] = true;
            map.put( sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], map.getOrDefault(sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], 0) + 1);
        } else {
            list.add(arr[i]);
            printSubsetsWithSum(i+1, arr, sum-arr[i], list, j+1, table, map);
            list.remove(j);
            printSubsetsWithSum(i+1, arr, sum, list, j, table, map);
            map.put( sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], map.getOrDefault(sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], 0) + 1);
            table[i][sum] = true;
        }
    }

    public static void printSubsetsWithSum(int sum, int[] arr) {
        boolean table[][] = new boolean[arr.length][sum+1];
        Map<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        printSubsetsWithSum(0, arr, sum, new ArrayList<>(), 0, table, map);
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSubsetsWithSum(10, new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});
    }
```

Please help ! ! !

Comment: Where is your matrix ??

Comment: The call happens using `printSubsetsWithSum(10, new int[] {1,2,3,4,5})`, there the boolean table is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printSubsetsWithSum(int i, int arr[], int sum, List<Integer> list, int j, boolean[][] table, Map<String,Integer> map) {
    if(sum == 0) {
        System.out.println(list);
    } else if(sum < 0 || i >= arr.length) {
        return;
    } else if(table[i][sum]) {
        return ;
    } else if(arr[i] > sum) {
        printSubsetsWithSum(i+1, arr, sum, list, j, table, map);
        table[i][sum] = true;
        map.put( sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], map.getOrDefault(sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], 0) + 1);
    } else {
        list.add(arr[i]);
        printSubsetsWithSum(i+1, arr, sum-arr[i], list, j+1, table, map);
        list.remove(j);
        printSubsetsWithSum(i+1, arr, sum, list, j, table, map);
        map.put( sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], map.getOrDefault(sum + "_" + i + "_" + arr[i], 0) + 1);
        table[i][sum] = true;// <<---- remove this line it works
    }
}
```

That line marks table[4][5] as true, i=4, list=[2, 3] sum=5 will match table[i][sum] == true

Comment: but after that I will b repeating a lot of combinations, it is to avoid repetitive calls for same combination of sum and i value

Comment: both [1,4,5] and [2,3,5] have the same i=4 and sum=5 @FurquanAhmed